# Could Not Load Static (JS/CSS) Files Over Proxy_Pass on SSL

Tags: php, wordpress, ssl, nginx, proxypass

I have to docker instances, one where it houses my Wordpress Installation composing of NGINX, PHP7.1 (PHP-FPM), MariaDD and Memcache containers. Those connect to an NGINX container that servers traffic to the outside world.

Everything works find over HTTP. When I switched to HTTPS, I ran into several issues. I've resolves some of them and I am left, I believe, with one issue of not being able to load to JS/CSS files.

Here is my Nginx Configuration on my Wordpress Container

```
server {
  listen 0.0.0.0:80;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/localhost.error.log;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/localhost.access.log;

  root /app/web;
  index index.php index.html index.htm;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
  }
}
```

Here is my Nginx Config on my Nginx container (The one that does the reverse_proxy)

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:433 ssl http2;
  server_name www.example.com;

  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem;
  ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
  
  sendfile off;
  error_log /dev/stdout info;
  access_log /dev/stdout;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://example-wordpress;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    
    proxy_set_header   SSL_PROTOCOL $ssl_protocol;
    proxy_set_header   SSL_CLIENT_CERT $ssl_client_cert;
    proxy_set_header   SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY $ssl_client_verify;
    proxy_set_header   SSL_SERVER_S_DN $ssl_client_s_dn;
  }

  location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|js|ico|xml)$ {
    expires 5d;
  }

  # deny access to . files, for security
  #
  location ~ /\. {
      log_not_found off; 
      deny all;
  }


  location ^~ /.well-known {
    allow all;
    auth_basic off;
  }

}
```

Here's what I did on my `wp-config.php`

```
if (
    (!empty( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'])) ||
    (!empty( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) )
{

  $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
}
```

This configuration manage to fix the redirect loop when I go to the admin side. But it doesn't load the the some css and JS files.

[image]

When I inspect the link, it directs me to a 404 page. I spun my local instance in my machine to see if the links were changed in some way. But comparing them, there're the same minus the domain.

```
https://www.example.com/app/themes/theme-v1.2/build/main.bundle.js?ver=1.0.0
http://www.example.local/app/themes/theme-v1.2/build/main.bundle.js?ver=1.0.0
```

I've spent a day figuring this out but I don't seem to know what else is there to get this last part done. I hope someone here can help me since it appears to be a nginx issue.

I would also include this [link](https://blog.chmouel.com/2016/09/22/the-trick-to-get-your-wordpress-behind-a-reverse-proxy/) since this helped me solved the redirect issue.

### Sumnmary

- I am running 2 dockers. One is wordpress one NGINX and a NGINX container that serves serves outbound traffic to the other containers.
- I am using `proxy_pass` to forward my traffic from `www.domain.com` to my nginx instance of my wordpress container.
- It works fine on HTTP. When I switch over HTTPS things didn't work.
- I manage to fix the redirect loop on the admin. But static files like JS and CSS fails to load.

Comment: You don't have `root /app/web;` in the `443` server block?

Comment: @TarunLalwani Yes, since its connecting via network. The app files are not on that container.

Comment: If that is the case you should remove `location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|js|ico|xml)$ {
    expires 5d;
  }`

Comment: @TarunLalwani Thanks. That Actually solved my case. I should've put that on my wordpress nginx container instead.

Answer (score 0):

put this codes in wp-config

```
define('FORCE_SSL_LOGIN', false);
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', false);
define( 'CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false );
define( 'SCRIPT_DEBUG', true );
```